# Add Dropdown Component to Material-Table Actions

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I can't seem to figure out how to place a custom dropdown component within the Action section in the top right portion of the material-table. Overriding the action component doesn't render anything.

**Below is what I had using a different table library, but what I'm going for with Material-Table.**

[image]

**Current Code**

```
<CustomMaterialTable
  title='Data Comparison'
  columns={tableCols}
  data={tableData}
  options={{
    exportButton: true,
    exportCsv: (columns, data) => { csvDownload(data, buildFileName(stateName)) },
    pageSize: tableData.length
  }}
  components={{
    Container: props => props.children,
    Action: props => (
      <YearDropDown
        year={year}
        type='secondary'
        minWidth='full'
        handleChange={handleYearChange}
        variant='outlined'
        required
      />
    )
  }}
/>
```

**CustomMaterialTable**

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import React from 'react'

export default function CustomMaterialTable (props) {
  return (
    <MaterialTable {...props} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are asking could be done by overriding the Action component as explained here, [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding).

Following that I ended up with this:

[image]

Of course you need to do some work on styling, but this could point you to the right direction.

Table definition, look at **components** and **action** props:

```
<MaterialTable
        tableRef={tableRef}
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={tableData}
        title="Custom Free Action example"
        options={{
          tableLayout: "fixed",
          actionsColumnIndex: -1,
          search: false,
          filtering: true
        }}
        components={{
          Action: props => (
            <div
              style={{
                marginBottom: "5rem",
                marginTop: "1rem",
                width: "150px"
              }}
            >
              <Select
                options={selectData}
              />
            </div>
          )
        }}
        actions={[
          {
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("something"),
            isFreeAction: true
          }
        ]}
      />
```

Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-select-as-custom-action-1ml0s?file=/src/App.js).

I don't know exactly what you are looking for but I added the filtering option to the table. Maybe that could be a different way to filter out data without having to overwrite the component and having to fight against the buil-in styles.

Hope this helps! good luck

Comment: Thank you! This helped push me along and I can display the custom field I need. However, when I combine my new custom field with `exportButton: false`, the export button overlaps with my new custom field. The search field works perfectly, but the export button does not. Any way around this without adding in my own custom export feature? I'd like to retain the built in `export to pdf` feature without having to build my own.

Comment: I was able to get it to look decent by adding `margin: '10px 10px 10px 2px', display: 'inline-flex'`. But I'm curious if there is a better way to do this... And additionally, is there a way to reorder the action buttons?

Comment: Glad that worked for you! I'm not sure how to go from here on. Since the initial question is pretty much resolved, maybe you can create a new more specific question regarding the action's re-ordering matter. Maybe that would draw more attention on that specific subject. good luck!

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Thank you so much for your help @NicoE